# re-lunching an android app from list of recent apps vs pressing on the app icon

Tags: android, resume

I have written an Android app that plays some audio. There is a stop button on the app GUI that when I first lunch the app works fine.
However when I go out of the app while audio is playing and come back depending on how I came back the `STOP` button works or not.
If I come back to the app by holding the home button and seeing the list of recent apps and choosing my app from there, then the `STOP` button works. But if I click on the app luncher icon the `STOP` button does not work.
What is the difference between these two method and how can I make the re-lunch of the app by pressing on the app icon to behave similar to when I re-lunch the app by choosing the app from the list of recent lunched apps.

Comment: Please show your onPause(), onStart() and onResume() methods.  Please don't post the entire code, just those.  People will ask for more if needed.

Comment: except onCreate() I don't have any other method.

Comment: Please learn about the Activity life cycle - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html.  You will need to handle these.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code we can't be entirely sure, but it sounds like what is happening is that your activity is you set up an action listener (`setOnClickListener`) on your stop button in your `onCreate()` method.

The `onCreate()` doesn't get called again if the app is never recycled (Android will do this when your app is put into the background) and started over.

When your app is put into the background `onPause()` will get called, then coming back from that you will get a call to `onResume()`.  If your app has been in the background longer or Android needed more resources you'll get a call to `onStop` hitting the home button and `onStart` when the app opens again.

You'll need to do some investigation into your code as to why your listener goes away, but now you have the hooks to make sure they are connected back up when you're app is back.